# Disable create and delete button for specific action/view openerp6.1

Tags: odoo

I create some report for warehouse in **openerp6.1** and i want to Disable create and delete buttons

I can't disable through access right because this object user in another form

Just disable buttons for specific form or action

(Screen shot)
[image]

Is it possible from some changes in **JavaScript** ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible.
Try to pass a key in context and override create and delete methods but it doesn't seem to be elegant.